# Notepad++ synchronize vertical scrolling

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and the file I am working on contains really lengthy lines. I want those lines to be viewed without scrolling sideways.I tried 'synchronize vertically' option but it didn't worked! How can I do that otherwise?

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: the key here is "word wrap" and is available in almost all editors including stupid Notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want those lines to be viewed without scrolling sideways

Enable "Word Wrap":

- Menu > "View" > "Word Wrap"

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question :) @DavidPostill